# VBA to increase the year after it finds a D

Tags: vba, loops, formula, offset

I have data from j14(January 14) until d14 which is in column C2:c13. I want the date to increase by 1 each time its ran so it goes from d14 to j15 f15 etc
Sheet 5 contains J-D in column a1:12 and 14 in b1:b12
I would like the range from c2:c13 to drop down one each run also

below is what i currently have but it only works for Jan15

```
Sub test()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim lastRow As String

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set SrchRng = Range("C2:C13")

For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "D") > 0 Then
    cel.Offset(1, 50).Value = Range("C" & lastRow).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sheet5!A1&Sheet5!B1+1"
End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: your search range is set to be 12 rows

Comment: I have just solved this by using "Range(Selection.Offset(-1, 0), Selection).FillDown". thanks for the reply

Comment: You should be using `Range("C2:C" & lastRow` I think